# Mountin electrical components and tubes inside an aluminum travel case

Tags: cases, mount

I've got a project involving al electric valve, water counter and some electronic parts (Arduino and similar). Of course, the electric valve and the water counter are connected with water pipes.

Is there a solution if I need to attach all these things inside an aluminum travel case? I've seen, for pipes, there are things called pipes' collar or something but, I still have to understand how to attach everything to the case.

Comment: Are you asking about how to attach pipe collars? That surely isn't in the "electrical" department.

Comment: Do you know how to use hot glue?

Comment: @Tyler no, I need to attach the water counter, the electric valve as well as the pipes

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yeah but, I would like to use something that I0m able to dismount too

Comment: @Tyler As you must learn. EE's are expected to know ME design for their own electro-mechanical issues. But I understand that is inconsistent with this room's policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was to use rings I've screwed on the side of the travel case. All the hydraulic components (electric valve, counter and water turbine) fixed with clamps to the rings.
About the electric component, we put them inside enclosures and fixed to the travel case via double side tape.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cheap washing machine AC water valve and a ZCS optoTriac and power Triac with properly shielded wires , AC earth ground and shield all sensor and power wires .

The valve and flow meter are external as the valve tends to use about 10W.(est.)  EMI filters on sensors will be necessary.

Comment: I'm not asking for components; I'm asking on how to attach them into a travel case

Comment: Attachment of which parts? PCB? valve? flowmeter? to what? a Waterproof case?  This mechanical problem can be solved with standoffs, bulkhead screws, adhesives, then determine best EMI immunity.  floating (? not without CM chokes)  Earth grounded? (opto isolated data ?) Switch noise?   Too many unknowns Pls specify Must haves. Or find a similar commercial solution!